# Trouble updating listview data

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an application that populates a `ListView` with user input data from another `Activity` ; however, whenever I enter that data into the second `Activity` then return to the `ListView` activity, I see it populated with the values I entered. But, if I return to the second activity again, enter the values, and go back to the `ListView` activity, I see the new values updated but the old ones have disappeared. 
Now, I don't know if I'm not updating the listview correctly or if I need to use SQLite databases to store this data or shared preferences in order to update the listview to new data while containing the previous information.

Thanks for any help.

ListActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.personalproject.peter.timerapp.TestingForAlarmData.TestAlarm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListOfAlarms extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int RESULT = 1000;

    List<TestAlarm> alarms = new ArrayList<>();
    String title;
    int totalTime;

    ListView listOfAlarms;
    ArrayAdapter<TestAlarm> alarmArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_alarms);



       final TextView emptyViewForList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyTextViewForList);

       listOfAlarms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
       alarmArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alarms);
       listOfAlarms.setAdapter(alarmArrayAdapter);

//        if(listOfAlarms.getCount() <= 0){
//            emptyViewForList.setText("No Alarms Currently Available");
//            listOfAlarms.setEmptyView(emptyViewForList);
//        }

        listOfAlarms.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               alarms.get(position);

                Intent clockDownActivity = new Intent(ListOfAlarms.this, CountDownAct.class);
               clockDownActivity.putExtra("Title", title);
               clockDownActivity.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
                startActivity(clockDownActivity);
           }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_of_alarms, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void goToFillOut(View view) {

            Intent goingToFillOut = new Intent(this, Test.class);
            startActivityForResult(goingToFillOut, RESULT);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){


               title = data.getStringExtra("title");
                totalTime = data.getIntExtra("totalTime", 0);

                alarms.add(new TestAlarm(title, totalTime));

               alarmArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }


}
```

SecondActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "Test.class";
    private static final long timeInterval = 1000;


    private Button complete;
    private EditText titleEditText;
    private EditText hourEditText;
    private EditText minuteEditText;
    private EditText secondEditText;
    public static   int hour;



    public static int minute;
    public static int second;
    public static String title;




    public int actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        hourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourEditText);
        minuteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minuteEditText);
        secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);

        complete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.completeButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void saveTimer(View view) {

        if(titleEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || hourEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                || minuteEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || secondEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you forgot one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }
//            complete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            title = titleEditText.getText().toString();
            hour = Integer.parseInt(hourEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            second = Integer.parseInt(secondEditText.getText().toString().trim());

            hour *= 3600000;
            minute *= 60000;
            second *= 1000;

        actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds = hour + minute + second;


        Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, ListOfAlarms.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("totalTime", actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }



}
```

Alarm.java

```
public class TestAlarm {

    public String title;
    public int totalTime;

    public TestAlarm (String title, int totalTime) {
        this.title = title;
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you by chance rotating your screen, or doing anything else that may destroy your previous activity? It seems like it may be getting recreated when you come back which will essentially empty your alarm list.

Comment: @dharms No its not being rotated, but I assume it has possibly something to do with recreating the list completely when entering the data. However, I do not know how to resolve that problem.

Comment: Android has some good documentation on how to handle this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: @dharms will onSavedInstance() do the trick? How would I save a list in there?

Comment: You could have your TestAlarm class implement Parcelable and use `Bundle.putParcelableArrayList()`.

Comment: @dharms could you make an example?